# Installed libssh2-php but no ssh2 with php -m

Tags: ubuntu, php, ssh, apt

I use php 5.5.3 on a Ubuntu 13.10 server and want to use ssh2 with php. So I installed libssh2-php with this command: `apt-get install libssh2-php`

Installation runs without error. I got a ssh2.ini file within /etc/php/conf.d. Restarted apache2 even rebooted the server but `php -m | grep ssh2` didn't return anything. `phpinfo()` got also no ssh entries :(

What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It's the same problem like mcrypt described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/362082/php-is-not-working-well-on-ubuntu-13-10-and-mcrypt-is-missing-in-phpmyadmin

to get ssh2 running you have to move the ssh2.ini from /etc/php/conf.d/ssh2.ini to /ect/php/mods-available/
Then run php5enmod ssh2 and restart apache2

Answer (score 0):

correct installation for enabling SSH2 in PHP is below for PHP7.4 and on word

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-ssh2
```

this command will eject /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/ssh2.ini in given PHP
as shown below

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

verification

```
more /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/ssh2.ini
extension=ssh2.so
php -m | grep ssh
ssh2
```

Now all is ok and working  ssh2 is PHP and apache2
you can also verify it from apache/PHP code in web
create file info.php in `/var/www/html/`

```
vi /var/www/html/info.php`
```

add following lines in above file

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

then search code  in web page ssh2